# Java NullPointerException due to indexing array

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23. Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

So it gives null pointer exception at `arr[i] = i;`. I am new to Java programming so I wanted to try arrays

```
 public class Multiples
    {
        private int arr[];
        private int sum = 0;

    public void multiples1()
      {
        for(int i= 0 ; i <= 1000; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = i ;
                if((i%3 == 0 && i%5==0))
                    {
                        sum = sum + arr[i];                         
                    }                   
            }   
        System.out.println(sum);
      }


}
```

Comment: You need to declare the size of your array! It's not enough to leave it blank.

Comment: @Floris - No, you don't declare the size of arrays in Java.  But you do need to create the arrays -- they don't create themselves/

Comment: you have to init the array, allocate memory to arr

Comment: just a note, if i%3 == 0 and i%5 == 0 then `i%15 ==0`

Comment: @HotLicks - initialize, declare... I was sloppy in my wording. It is late here (and Java is not "my" language). Thanks for pointing out the correct phrase.

Comment: "multiples of 3 OR 5" - implies that you should use the `||` operator, not the `&&` operator, in your `if` statement!

Comment: @Floris - I see related mistakes made in Objective-C quite often.  In some case people believe they must "declare" a pointer by initializing it with an object (which they immediately discard by overwriting with a new object).  Or they believe that simply declaring a pointer is equivalent to initializing it with an object of that type.

Comment: @HotLicks - I have no argument with you there. The simple lack of making sure that the compiler assigns valid memory locations for the objects you want to manipulate in your code must account for half the bugs in the known universe.

Answer (score 4):

- It should be `private int arr[] = new int[arraySize];`
- An array is an `Object` so if you don't initialize it using `new int[size]`, it will be `null`.
- If you perform operation of a reference variable that is referring to `null`, you will face `NullPointerException`

Your revised code would be:

```
public class Multiples
    {
        private int arr[] = new int[1000];
        private int sum = 0;

    public void multiples1()
      {
        for(int i= 0 ; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = i ;
                if((i%3 == 0 && i%5==0))
                    {
                        sum = sum + arr[i];                         
                    }                   
            }   
        System.out.println(sum);
      }


}
```

Comment: You mean `int[1000]` right...?

Comment: @Floris, yes actually, thats why I edited and just said `arraySize`

Comment: Only if he doesn't want an array indexing exception.

Comment: @HotLicks, yes of course :)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply everyone. But it gives java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Comment: @JohnSmith, becauese of your for loop `for(int i= 0 ; i <= 1000; i++)`, here it is trying to access 1001st index so change it to `for(int i= 0 ; i < 1000; i++)` after you create array as `new int[1000]`

Comment: @John Smith Java arrays are zero based, hence, a 10 element array has indexes 0 to 9. As Prasad said, you'll need the end condition of your loop to be < 1000 rather than <= 1000

Comment: Thanks! it works. I am new to programming as a lot of other people and thanks to you all, newbies like us learn. Thanks again!

Comment: @JohnSmith we are all learners :)

Comment: @PrasadKharkar - Nah, I haven't learned anything new since 1973 -- it seems like I just run into the same stuff again and again in different contexts.  (And, unfortunately, I seem to make the same mistakes again and again as well.)

Comment: @HotLicks, oops, I should have written I'm a learner.

Comment: You need OR, not AND, in the if statement, in order to achieve what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet would do what you want to achieve.

```
public class Multiples
{
    private int arr[] = new int[1001];
    private int sum = 0;

public void multiples1()
  {
    for(int i= 0 ; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = i ;
            if((i%3 == 0 && i%5==0))
                {
                    sum = sum + arr[i];                         
                }                   
        }   
    System.out.println(sum);
  }
}
```